# Working example of the localnotification phonegap plugin

Tags: cordova, plugins, localnotification

I spent hours and hours trying to make the localnotification phonegap plugin work. I read many stackoverflow answers and try many Cordova, Eclipse, Android versions, but without any succes. Problems with identifying plugin variable, R.drawable.ic_launcher and many other things in the Java files. I know a bit of javascript, but nothing of Java.

I really would like to build my free Breathe, Smile, Relax reminder alert app. I believe this app can help everybody with their day to day challenges.

Can anyone please share a working example of an Eclipse localnotification project with me. I would really appreciate that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're talking about this plugin right?: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/LocalNotification Did you see the note about changing that ic_launcher icon to a file you actually have in your project?